# Why is calling an interface method directly from the interface (with no implementation) working?

Tags: java, methods, interface, libgdx

This is from LibGDX framework, i'm calling the method

```
Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT);
```

This is the relevant part of Gdx class:

```
public class Gdx {

    //..
    public static Input input;
    //..
}
```

And the relevant part of Input:

```
public interface Input {

    //..
    public class Keys { //..
    }
    //..
    public boolean isKeyPressed (int key);
    //..

}
```

The worst thing is that it´s working !! Returns true if i'm pressing the left arrow.

I don't understand why, it looks as if I'm calling an interface method without the implementation.

I'm leaving the link to the source code of both classes:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Gdx.java

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.java

Comment: It is implemented elsewhere in the library via concrete code, perhaps native code, and assigned to the static field.

Comment: There's a class implementing this interface for each backend. For example, there's [LwjglInput](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglInput.java) and [AndroidInput](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidInput.java). If you use the debugger and check what type is `Gdx.input` value, you'll know what class is being used.

Answer (score 0):

From the [source code](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Gdx.html):

```java
/** Environment class holding references to the {@link Application}, {@link Graphics}, {@link Audio}, {@link Files} and
 * {@link Input} instances. The references are held in public static fields which allows static access to all sub systems. Do not
 * use Graphics in a thread that is not the rendering thread.
 * <p>
 * This is normally a design faux pas but in this case is better than the alternatives.
 * @author mzechner */
public class Gdx {
    public static Application app;
    public static Graphics graphics;
    public static Audio audio;
    public static Input input;
    public static Files files;
    public static Net net;

    public static GL20 gl;
    public static GL20 gl20;
    public static GL30 gl30;
}
```

So  you can see the documentation says this class holds references to **instances** of `Application`, `Graphics`, `Audio` and `Input`. But how and where are they implemented?

LibGDX knows which type of device it is running on and chooses to implement accordingly, for example in the [`Input`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/Input.html) implementation case if we are running on an Android device we would go with the [`AndroidInput`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidInput.java) implementation:
[image]

And all of this is done automatically for us under the hood so we focus more on making a great game/app.
So really when we use:

```java
Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT);
```

We are using the correct implementation of `Input` for our device and not calling the method from the interface itself.